# How to pass value to jqgrid toolbar search box

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I would like to pass a search value to one of the columns in the jsgrid. Can this be done?

Say I have a grid with the following columns:

City, Size, and Postal Code

I would like to pass in a postal code value to display in the toolbar search box and then run the search.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the text fields of the searching toolbar by ids. The id of the filed will be build based on the value of `name` property of the column in `colModel` and the prefix `"gs_"`. For example if you have columns with `name="city"` then to set the value `"London"` in the corresponding input field you can use `$("#gs_city").val("London")`. After you set all the values which you need you can trigger `change` event on any of the elements of the toolbar to apply the filtering on the grid. Alternatively one can call `triggerToolbar` method saved on DOM element of the grid: `$("#gridid")[0].triggerToolbar();`.